# Display tier price in configurable product type

Tags: magento

How can I display tier price in magento for configurable products?

Answer (score 0):

Have you even tried anything at all? Googling for 'tier price' returned me this as the first result:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-use-tier-pricing

Comment: yes i have try this but if i assign tier price to All Groups then it is display but i want to assign tier price for only one groups like Wholesale this way tier price is not display on product page

Comment: Read the page I linked to. When adding a tier price, you can select this under the 'Customer group' tab.